# Bluetooth support in C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I am looking for a Bluetooth stack for C# that will allow me to route audio from my phone to my computer, as well as use my microphone on my computer(Windows 7) as an input device for phone calls on my phone. I've looked at 32Feet.NET, but it does not seem to support audio channels. If I am wrong on this, someone please correct me. Otherwise, if there an alternate library for C# that I can use for Bluetooth support?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this probably doesn't really answer your question, but maybe adds some alternative perspective: The issues you're trying to solve seem to be supported by standard Bluetooth audio profiles. As such, there are chances they're provided by the OS's (or other vendor's) Bluetooth stack in a transparent manner, i.e. as audio device like the system's sound card.

If there is no urgent reason for a custom implementation of these Bluetooth profiles, you might be better off looking for .NET methods that configure the audio devices your code uses for audio input/output. You would then use Bluetooth audio in the same way you access other audio devices, basically reducing your code to proxy audio from one audio device (sound card) to another (Bluetooth audio).